# Embed Airtable on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, airtable

I am trying to embed an Airtable Base onto a Wordpress blog. By using the default embed code generated by Airtable, blank space is displaying on my site. Any ideas?

Website:
https://danielstojanovski.wordpress.com/resources/

```
<iframe class="airtable-embed" src="https://airtable.com/embed/shrlKBS7YH4pR0D72?backgroundColor=orange" frameborder="0" onmousewheel="" width="100%" height="533" style="background: transparent; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></iframe>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can confirm your embed code works on sites other than WordPress (e.g. try pasting it into https://htmledit.squarefree.com) have you tried to add iFrames using a WordPress plugin, such as iFrame or Advanced iFrame? As demonstrated at https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-iframe/#3-add-iframes-to-wordpress-using-a-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone still stumbles upon this issue in the future, this was 100% related to your WP/plugin setup. Namely, something on the site was breaking the iFrames, which otherwise tend to render in everything from local HTML files to Notion docs and "serverless" caching setups.